# Unable to pass text to a text box

Tags: python, selenium

Follwing is the HTML code:

```
<div class="search-nav">
    <div class="field">
        <input id="search" type="text" class="input-data" 
                placeholder="Enter Claim or Payment Number..." 
                name="QuickSearch">
        </input>
    </div>
    <button class="search-button" data-ng-click="performSearch($event)"> 
    <i class="search icon"></i></button>
</div>
```

Python selenium code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='field' and @id='search']"))).send_keys("12343545")
```

Comment: share relevant HTML

Comment: @cruisepandey - the html was in the post but the OP had failed to indent it so it was not visible

Comment: where is input tag ends ? where is </input> ?

Comment: there is no closing tag for <input>. thou, there is an iframe: <iframe data-ng-repeat="frame in frames" data-app-home="sss" id="payspan-health" frameborder="0" data-ng-src="fff" data-ng-show="frame.show" class="ng-scope" src="pp" style="height: 489px;"></iframe>

Comment: After this textbox code is the seach button code:    <button class="search-button" data-ng-click="performSearch($event)"><i class="search icon"></i></button>

Comment: your xpath is wrong, use "//div[@class='field']/input[@id='search']"

Comment: Is input or button field is in iframe ?

Comment: yea they are in iframe

Comment: leme try with this xpath

Comment: @DimpleMathew do try my answer.

Comment: Okay then I''ll provide the code !

Comment: Share HTML for `iframe` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks there is a `frame` there, you first swithc to frame then locate element

```
//Switch to frame    
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("Id of your Frame")) 

waitElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = waitElem .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'search'))) 

element.send_keys("323232")
```

Please place your frame locator in place of "Id of your Frame"

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot pass text is because you are looking for an element where `class = 'field'` and `id = 'search'`. With this, you are referring to 2 different element. `class = 'field'` is a `<div>` and and `id = 'search'` is an `<input>`

What you want to do is, send text to the input only. Now if you want to send it to this specific input under the div with `class = 'field'` try the following:

```
//div[@class='field']/input[@id='search']"))).send_keys("12343545")
```

Or if this is the only input field with id "search".

```
//input[@id='search' and @class='input-data']
```

Comment: I tried that it didnot work: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='field']/input[@id='search']"))).send_keys("12343545")

Answer (score 0):

If the input field is in iframe then you have to switch control of webdriver to that particular iframe for performing any operations inside it :

**Code**

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("payspan-health"))  
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'search')))
driver.find_element_by_id('search').send_keys("12343545")

#To switch back to the main window, you can use
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: tru out this code and let me know the status whether it worked for you or not ?

Comment: Since you have already accepted the answer from imsankalp89 .Did you try out the code provided by me ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently your Xpath is referring to nothing as there is no such Web Element with id and class you are referring to.

'AND' can only be used in xpath on two attributes present in same tag.
Eg: //input[@id='search' AND name='QuickSearch']

So, Update your xpath as:

//input[@id='search']  OR
//input[@id='search' AND @name='QuickSearch']